# Using filter pattern in AWS-CLI logs

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to filter log events from AWS cloud watch logs using awscli. I use the following pattern in the cloudwatch web console.

`[ip, user, username, timestamp, request, status_code != 2*, bytes]`

What is the equivalent filter pattern I should use in awscli? I tried `aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name *** --log-stream-name *** --filter-pattern "[ip, user, username, timestamp, request, status_code != 2*, bytes]"` but it didn't filter anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
aws logs filter-log-events \
--start-time `date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Mon Apr 16 14:25:43 PDT 2018" "+%s"`000 \
--end-time `date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Mon Apr 16 14:45:43 PDT 2018" "+%s"`000 \
--log-group-name <log-group-name> \
--filter-pattern "[ip, user, username, timestamp, request, status_code != 2*, bytes]" \
--output text
```

Replace the appropriate values.

Answer (score 1):

This is some code for a function I wrote for the purpose of gathering daily postfix logs. One thing I noticed is that putting the filter pattern in a variable in a bash script gets complex because of the need to have single quotes and double quotes in the string so I just skipped that idea. I'm sure it can be done, but the complexity wasn't worth it in my case.

```
# Purpose: Collect postfix mail relay CloudWatch Logs for the last day
# Arguments:
#  1 is the AWS region, defaults to $DATA_CENTER
#  2 is the AWS log-group-name to use
# Dependencies: aws cli
function getCloudWatchLogs {
  region=${1:-$DATA_CENTER}
  log-group-name=${2:-"mail_out/postfix"}
  aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name ${log-group-name} \
    --start-time $(date --date "yesterday 00:00:00" +%s%N | cut -b1-13) \
    --end-time $(date --date "yesterday 23:59:59" +%s%N | cut -b1-13) \
    --filter-pattern='[month, day, time, instance, process="*]:", id="*:", recipient="to=<*>,", message!="*status=sent*"]' \
    --region ${region} --output text \
    | awk -F"\t" '{print $5}'|cut -d" " -f6- \
    > $mail_dir/postfixmaillog_${region}.out
}
```

Comment: If someone makes this better, please post your changes. I'm sure it can be done.